# How do you set an edge length in Diagrammer?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I do not want an edge label to overlap a node. Can this be done manually? Can the edge length be set to not overlap nodes for all edge labels?
Thank you.

E.g. red edge:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph circo { 

  graph[layout = circo,
    overlap=false]  

  node[shape = circle,
       style=filled,
       color = grey,
       label = 'my label']
A[label='Jeffrey Jones']; B; C; D; E; F 

node[shape= rectangle]
1[label='This is a long label number 1']; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7[label=number7];

# add edge statements 
A-> 1[label='This is my edge label', color=red, len=30.0]; B-2; B->3; B->4; C->A

}
")
```

[image: chunk output]

Answer (score 0):

I think, this easy example will help to you:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph {
  graph [ranksep = 0.2]
node [shape = circle]
  A [label = 'Jeffrey Jones']
  node [shape = rectangle]
  B [label = 'This is a long label number']
  C [label = 'Age']
edge [minlen = 3] #set minimum length here
  A->B [label='This is my edge label   ']
  A->C
  {rank = same; A; B}
}
")
```

[image]

Start from basics and after grow faster.

Good luck ;)